# Rails How to use join in this specific situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have three models, each connected as such: `Groups` which has many `Students` which has many `Absences`.

`Absences` has a field called `created_on`.

**I only have a *group id* and would like to obtain all *students* with an *absence* of today.**

I have created this method inside my `Student` model:

```
# Inside student.rb

def self.absent_today_in_group (group)
 #SQLITE
 find(:all, :joins => :absences, :conditions => ["STRFTIME('%d', created_on) = ? AND STRFTIME('%m', created_on) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month])

 #POSTGRES
 #find(:all, :joins => :absences, :conditions => ["EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_on) = ? AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created_on) = ?", Date.today.day, Date.today.month])
end
```

Why would that query not return anything? And how could I then also check for group_id?

Comment: What does the log tell you about the generated SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of rails are you using? You can do this in rails 3:

```
def self.absent_today_in_group(group)
  joins(:absences, :group).where(
    'absences.created_on' => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day),
    'groups.id' => group.id
  )
end
```

That would find all users which were absent for today for given group.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Rails3, and this now works in dev for SQlite, would it work for PostGres (on heroku)?

Comment: Btw, its always good practice to match your development environment to your production one (if possible). So, it would be good idea to instal postgres on your local machine and do the development using it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt this be :where and not :conditions?

Comment: Yepp..my fault, sorry!! I usually use the method syntax, and then its .where([...])